# How do you launch an SSH connection with port forwarding without interrupting your screen access?

Tags: ssh, interactive, port-forwarding

I want to make an SSH connection to another server with forwarding, but without having to log on to the remote server, nor interfere with the  screen I am working on. I also need to access the connection to terminate it when I finish with it.

eg. say I want to do a mysql backup on a remote server so I use the command `ssh user@remote -L 1234:localhost:3306` but after issuing the password I want to run the mysql command in the session, but be able to access the SSH connection when I finish with mysql and terminate it.

Is there some way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU screen, it should be installed on all Linux boxes by default.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Here is a good starters guide.

http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935

Comment: answer is a bit short, perhaps you can add a brief summary of the guide

Comment: I think I have to explain myself better. It is all being done from the same window/screen automatically. I shouldn't have to switch to another Window or screen. Both the SSH command and the Mysql command should run from the same command line without switching.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script with AutoHotKey to open the window, run the command(s) and then minimize the window for you to deal with later.

Comment: I am running Linux via SSH. It isn't Windows